# UIButton inside custom UIView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I've a custom UIView that appears when some error happens in my app. It has a close button (UIButton) that will close the "error showing view" when user click on it. The problem that I'm facing now is there is no action performs inside my custom view, when user click on the close button and the error view is not being removed. Do I have to modify some code or need to add some in order to make my button action work inside a custom view?

**Here is my code snippet**:

```
class GeneralErrorHandler: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var closeButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var errorTxtLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

let theView:UIView

init(errorText:String, view:UIView, position:CGPoint){
    theView = view
    super.init(frame:CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 62))

    Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed("GeneralErrorView", owner: self, options: nil)

    contentView.frame = self.frame
    errorTxtLbl.text = errorText

    closeButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forceCloseButton), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func show(){
    theView.addSubview(contentView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    theView = UIView()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed("GeneralErrorView", owner: self, options: nil)
    closeButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forceCloseButton), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func forceCloseButton(){
    contentView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
}
}
```

I have a NSError extension that calls GeneralErrorHandler and I pass the ViewController's view where I want the error to appear

```
extension NSError {

    func showErrorScreen(view:UIView, position:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero){

        if isInternetAvailable() {
            print("Inernet is availble, another error happened")
            GeneralErrorHandler(errorText: self.errorMessage(), view: view, position: position).show()

        }else{
            print("Internet not available")
            ConnectionError(view: view, position:position).show()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try enabling the user interaction to the view.

Comment: can you post how are you using your custom view?

Comment: this is swift why do u put objective c tag??!?!!??!?

Comment: Can you post the code how do you use the theView in your viewController class?

Comment: @Frederico Novack Amaral Pereir : You sure your code shows GeneralErrorHandler on calling show() I am facing crash because its resulting in infinite recursive call of init

Comment: @the4kman tried enabling user interaction in the view and it did not work

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes it shows the GeneralErrorHandler... the only thing that doesn't happen is the button action

Comment: I'm sorry my ignorance, but how did you use `IBOutlet` inside an `UIView` ? If it is a miss typing, how did you use `self.frame` if `UIViewController` doesn't have this property ? Is this your real code ?

Comment: If it is your real code (I doubt) the selector syntax must contain the target class and usually your target is your viewcontroller then it would be `#selector(GeneralErrorHandler.forceCloseButton)`

Comment: This is my real code =)

Comment: @GIJOW GeneralErrorHandler is a subclass of UIView... not UIViewController... I shouldn't be using IBOutlet inside a UIView? Always done that and always worked... don`t remember doing a button action on a UIView though

Comment: using #selector(GeneralErrorHandler.forceCloseButton) not working too

Comment: Are you using XIB ?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to forceCloseButton and see if it's invoked when clicking the close button.

Comment: Trying to be objective critical.... (1) This seems like a lot of work to do for generic error handling. Why not simply use `UIAlertController`? 4 lines of code wrapped in a function has the same functionality as this. (2) What does the overhead of loading a nib file do to your project? (3) If for some reason you still want to go this route, why not code a `UIPresentationController` and then present it? Seems *much* easier than working with a nib.

Comment: great ideas @dfd... I'll checkout about UIPresentationController. 
About UIAlertController, I can't use it because of the alert design...

Comment: I present a `UIViewController` "nearly" full screen (auto layout it to 80%). It has a table view and a close button. It's fairly easy to code it. You may be able to use a nib file, I honestly don't know. Either way, you probably want to make sure you instant things as little as possible. That's my biggest things about the code you've shown - if you are calling `GeneralErrorView` in a way that instantiates it time and time again, it feels like you could improve the design.